# Totally Unimodular Matrices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, unimodular-matrices

Given a non-squared $M$, and a square $N$ totally unimodular matrices (TUM), is it true that if I consider
$$
   HM = MC
$$
then is it so that $H$ must be TUM? I know that $MC$ must be TUM as the product of two TUMs is TUM, but is it possible to have a non-TUM that multiplies a TUM and gives a TUM?

Comment: Yep, I just found a simple counterexample: $H=[2,1;2,1]$ and $M=[-1,1,1;1,-1,1]$

Comment: There is a mistake in my statement. It is not true that the product of two TUM is TUM ...